# When transferring data through $customerSession, I receive data locally, but not on the production

Tags: magento2, php, session, php-7, customer-session

I have a custom functionality for creating an order, I want to transfer the custom LastOrderId to the success page to which the user gets after submitting the form.

The controller responsible for submitting the form returns a redirect
`app/code/Qq/Www/Controller/Order/Create.php`

`return $resultRedirect->setPath('dv_sample/success');`

The controller responsible for rendering the success page
`app/code/Qq/Www/Controller/Success/Index.php`

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private $pageFactory;

    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->customerSession->getLastSampleRealOrderId()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('building-bed-page');
        }
        return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Block `app/code/Qq/Www/Block/Success.php`

```
    protected $customerSession;

    public $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function lastSampleRealOrderId()
    {
        $incrementOrderId = $this->customerSession->getLastSampleRealOrderId();

        if ($incrementOrderId) {
            $this->customerSession->setLastSamleRealOrderId(null);
        }

        return $incrementOrderId;
    }
```

Template `app/code/Qq/Www/view/frontend/templates/success/index/success_page.phtml`

After submitting the form locally, I get a saxest page in which I see all the data including the ID order. `<?= $block->lastSampleRealOrderId() ?>`

But after uploading to the server, the order is not visible, data does not come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies on the surface, but you don’t see it.

experience has shown that many developers turn off block, full page, and layout caches when developing.

most likely you have them enabled for production. try temporarily disabling `full page cache` and you will see your result.

if this helps add `cacheable="false"` to your layout